# C++11 feature std::map::at compiling on older versions of C++

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, g++, c++03

The code below uses `std::map::at` which was introduced in c++11, however, while specifying an older version (I've tried `-std=c++03`, `-std=c++0x` and `-std=c++98`) in g++ and cmake, it still gets compiled. Other c++11 features do not work, such as range-based for loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> my_map;
    my_map[0] = 1;
    std::cout << my_map.at(0);
    return 0;
}
```

g++ command:

```
g++ -std=c++03 -o main *.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(test)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++03")
add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

Output in both cases:

```
1
```

What could be the issue here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: library might have forget `#ifdef` around `at`. (or providing as extension).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen g++ and gcc both (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

Comment: all I tested on godbolt dont error also `-pedantic` doesnt help

Comment: is it really a problem? I mean if it works then it works. If you want to make sure to be portable, then anyhow you should also compile with a different compiler.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: No errors [here](https://godbolt.org/z/7BpJgU), not with clang neither.

Comment: @Nick: `-std=c++0x` is not really an older version, just partial support of unfinished C++11.

Comment: The standard only specifies what must exist and does not prohibit an implementation from including other member functions and features.

Comment: @idclev463035818 It is a problem. For my assignments the code I write needs to compile in VS2008, however I am on linux. However, while I can most of the times write a code that doesn't use new features, mistakes do occur and I do not have a way to be sure it compiles on older versions. The issue described in a post was one of them.

Comment: yes you do have a way to check if it compiles on older versions: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: I hope it was. As mentioned in a comment above by @Jarod42 it doesn't show an error either and moreover, I can only run a single file that doesn't use any external libraries, which, my projects, do depend on

Comment: My bad. The error was actually pointing to a different header I used, not to `at()` method.

Comment: godbolt also has msvc, which btw also does not error on `at`

Comment: @Nick you can always set up a low-end environment with the compiler only, for example a Windows XP VM with [this standalone compiler setup](http://blog.httrack.com/blog/2014/02/21/fancy-standalone-visual-c-plus-plus-compiler/). That's what I did to develop on Linux for MSVC 2008 to 2013.

Comment: @LuisMachuca Yes, I got it running on VM, thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to discussion at https://en.cppreference.com/w/Talk:cpp/container/map/at
indeed `std::map::at` was missing in the original [C++98 standard](http://www.lirmm.fr/%7Educour/Doc-objets/ISO+IEC+14882-1998.pdf)

Technically `std::map::at` appeared in Library Working Group [LWG 464](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue464) and adopted into the 2008 standard draft. On the other hand, it seems compilers did implement LWG 464 as a defect report. Clang, GCC, MSVC - these are all enabled it in C++98 mode.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Typically, std::lib vendors treat LWG issues as "bug fixes" that should be applied to older standard modes as well. Nowadays the committee would not accept new APIs like this as a "bug fix" and would insist on a real proposal to go through the Library Evolution Working Group's design process. But back in 2008 we did things differently, and this was handled as a bug fix for C++03!